# PZEM-004 cheaper alternatives

Tags: communication, energy-monitoring-systems

I am an programmer, trying to monitor consumption remotely, I need some form of communication via cable to transmit (even if I trasmit it WIFi later), PZEM-004 for me is very expensive, and I don't need to calculate more than 50A. Other options? By the way, there is cheap digital amperimeters in the market, but they just show the values in their own digital displays, some way to transmit the values to an computer?

Comment: Actually, I find the PZEM004 very cheap. If it does not fit your project, you can spend some more time and do your power calculations using a SCT013.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy your own voltage sensor and current sensor. Hook it up to an Arduino and you would be able to see the measurements on the serial monitor. This is the cheapest way of doing it.

One of the major downsides would be accuracy since you are putting everything together yourselves. The data can be noisy.

Comment: Just average the data! I am guessing by cheap sensors, and fidgety values you meant a acs712 or similar? what are you using for measurements?